# Could someone explain this function to me?

Tags: haskell

this function maps letters onto another letter. Could someone explain to me what does the `!! 0` mean here in the function?

```
findGuess letter guessList 
  | length guessList == 0 = (letter, letter)
  | letter == snd (guessList !! 0) || letter == fst (guessList !! 0) = guessList !! 0
  | otherwise = findGuess letter (tail guessList)
```

Comment: Avoid using `length`, `head`, `tail` and `!!`. And in particular never write `length l == 0`, because it needs to traverse the entire list to compute the length, though all that's really needed is to check whether it's `[]`.

Comment: Expression `(length list == 0)` can always be replaced by `(null list)`. This is more efficient, and does not diverge when the input list is infinite (which is perfectly legal in Haskell).

Answer (score 5):

`(!!)` is the (partial) indexing operator for lists. `guessList !! 0` is basically equivalent to `head guessList`. Neither is recommended, as they only work when `guessList` is not empty. Prefer pattern matching:

```
findGuess letter [] = (letter, letter)
findGuess letter ((c1, c2):rest) | letter == c1 || letter == c2 = (c1, c2)
                                 | otherwise = findGuess letter rest
```

As an aside, `findGuess` mosty reimplements `Data.List.find`:

```
import Data.List

findGuess letter guessList = case find p guessList of
                               Nothing -> (letter, letter)
                               Just x -> x
     where p (c1, c2) = letter == c1 || letter == c2
```

Answer (score 0):

guessList !! 0 is equal to guessList[0] in Java/C#...
So, this function check if letter matches the first or second of head pair tuple of the list, after that recursively continue to check all items of list.

Comment: Superficially,  yes. But indexing operations in Java and C# are constant-time operations, while `x !! k` is O(n) in Haskell, due to `[]` producing a linked-list data structure.